# LINQ to SQL - WHERE clause filtered

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Why is the `where` condition not applied in the following code?  When I search, the results are not getting filtered.  When I debug, `searchString` does have a value and execution is going through the `_data.Where` clause but it's not returning the filtered result.

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
IQueryable<UserViewModel> _data = (
    from a in context.aspnet_Users
    join b in context.aspnet_Membership on a.UserId equals b.UserId
    where b.IsApproved == true
    select new UserViewModel
    {                                 
        UserId = a.UserId,
        UserName = a.UserName,
        FirstName = a.FirstName,
        LastName = a.LastName,
        EmailAddress = b.Email                                 
    })
    .OrderBy(a => a.FirstName)
    .ThenBy(b => b.LastName);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{                  
   _data = _data
        .Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(searchString))
        .Where(y => y.UserName.Contains(searchString))
        .Where(y => y.LastName.Contains(searchString))
        .Where(y => y.EmailAddress.Contains(searchString));
}
```

Comment: I assume only the second query is relevant. This query tries to find records where FirstName *and* UserName *and* LastName *and* Email all start with the same string. I think what you wanted is a query that checks simly if any of them starts with the search string

Comment: How have you verified this result?  What is the unfiltered data, what is the search string, and what is the filtered data?  Are you sure you're using a search string that exists in *all four* of those fields for any given record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is doing a lot more "filtering" than you expect:

```
_data = _data.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(searchString))
             .Where(y => y.UserName.Contains(searchString))
             .Where(y => y.LastName.Contains(searchString))
             .Where(y => y.EmailAddress.Contains(searchString));
```

This requires that `searchString` exist in *all four* of those fields.  So if you search for, say, "David" then it's going to fail to find my record because my `LastName` doesn't contain that string.

Perhaps you wanted to use a logical *or* instead of a logical *and*?  Something like this:

```
_data = _data.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(searchString) ||
                         x.UserName.Contains(searchString) ||
                         x.LastName.Contains(searchString) ||
                         x.EmailAddress.Contains(searchString));
```

Answer (score 1):

The way the second query is written checks for records where *all* filtered fields start with the search string, ie for users whose FirstName *and* LastName *and* UserName *and* Email all start with the same string.

I think what you wanted was a query that check whether any of these fields starts with the search string, eg:

```
_data = _data.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(searchString) ||
                         x.UserName.Contains(searchString)  ||
                         x.LastName.Contains(searchString)  ||
                         x.EmailAddress.Contains(searchString));
```